# highlighting elastic search results using elastic search-php

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am  trying to highlight my results in elastic search-php , I tried a lot with my knowledge and searching in google, but no luck , the same query is working perfectly in Sense. my query in Sense is

```
GET /bank/account/_search
{
"query" : {
    "match_phrase" : {
        "address" : "mill"
    }
},
"highlight": {
    "pre_tags" : ["<tag1>"],
    "post_tags" : ["</tag1>"],
    "fields" : {
        "address" : {}
    }
}
}
```

with above query i get exact result what i needed, this is the result i got

```
highlight": {
           "address": [
              "990 <tag1>Mill</tag1> Road"
           ]
        }
```

i tried the same query using php i am not get the highlighted results my php query is

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$client=new  Elasticsearch\Client();
$indexParams = [
        'index' => 'bank',
        'type'  => 'account',
        'body'  => [
            'query' => [
                'match' => [
                    "address" => "mill"
                ],                
    ], 
    'highlight' => [
                "pre_tags"  => "<tag1>",
                "post_tags" => "</tag1>",
                'fields'    => [
                   'address' => new \stdClass()
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ];
$results = $client->search($indexParams);
try {            
$response = $client->search($indexParams);
} catch (Exception $e) {            
var_dump($e->getMessage());        
}
echo '<pre>',print_r($response),'</pre>';
?>
```

the result i aam getting is

```
[highlight] => Array
                            (
                                [address] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 715 Mill Avenue
                                    )

                            )
```

Answer (score 1):

i got the answer for above question, i am sending parameters in the form of json and JSON encode the result, when i encode the result in JSON at that pre tags are came in highlight query.

my solution is

```
"highlight": {
      "address": [
        "817 Campus </span>Road</span>"
      ]
    }
```